# Choice of buffer pH to avoid aggregation

Tags: purification, proteins

I want to purify IgG which has a theoretical pI of 6.4-9.0 with an anion exchange column. I also want to keep the pH of my buffers as low as possible and "outside" the range of the pI to prevent aggregation.

Still, I will need to increase the pI so that IgG will have negative net charge and bind to the column. What pH do you think I should choose in order to have the IgG binding to the column and to prevent aggregation as much as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an extraordinarily wide pI range, perhaps its because you a purifying an IgG with very many subunits (?). In that case, it might not be good idea to purify this by the means of anion exchange. 'Common' globular proteins (monomers, dimer, trimers or tetramers etc) have one theoretical pI, and you keep the pH of the buffer at approx. 1.0 pH unit above or below the theoretical pI value - preferably towards physiological pH values (to retain proper activity). In the case of anion exchange you need to think of the surfaces charges.